# Using CloudFlare's Load Balancer with Wordpress Multisite Across Domains

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, cloudflare

I currently have a single Wordpress site, `example.com` on CloudFlare with Load Balancing. I'm transitioning this site over to a Wordpress Multisite install so it'll host `example.com`, `foobar.com`, and `example2.com`.

[Cloudflare's guide](https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/how-to/create-load-balancer/) mentions that *You can share your load balancer with other sites in your account...* just by adding a CNAME. But this doesn't make any sense, as under my Cloudflare site `example.com` I can't just add a DNS record for `foobar.com`.

Does anyone know how I can get a Cloudflare load balancer to respond to multiple domains and them be routed to the same pool of origin servers?